# Error while installing NumPy package in PyCharm

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I have tried to install the NumPy package in PyCharm and am getting this error:

> error: Could not initialize compiler instance: do you have Visual Studio

[image: error]

I have already installed Visual Studio 2015 and upgraded setup tools. please help me resolve this

```
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/de/0ea5092b8bfd2e3aa6fdbb2e499a9f9adf810992884d414defc1573dca3f/numpy-1.18.1.zip
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: still running...
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command "C:\Users\Badboy\PycharmProjects\my python projects\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\Badboy\PycharmProjects\my python projects\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py" prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel C:\Users\Badboy\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpi7a2_egc:
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    Cythonizing sources
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\Badboy\\PycharmProjects\\my python projects\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\Badboy\\PycharmProjects\\my python projects\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Badboy\\PycharmProjects\\my python projects\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Badboy\\PycharmProjects\\my python projects\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Badboy\\PycharmProjects\\my python projects\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Badboy\\PycharmProjects\\my python projects\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Badboy\\PycharmProjects\\my python projects\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\Badboy\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Badboy\\PycharmProjects\\my python projects\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\Badboy\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\Badboy\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
      NOT AVAILABLE

    'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\Badboy\\PycharmProjects\\my python projects\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Badboy\\PycharmProjects\\my python projects\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\Badboy\\PycharmProjects\\my python projects\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\Badboy\\PycharmProjects\\my python projects\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Badboy\PycharmProjects\my python projects\venv\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Badboy\PycharmProjects\my python projects\venv\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Badboy\PycharmProjects\my python projects\venv\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Badboy\PycharmProjects\my python projects\venv\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Badboy\PycharmProjects\my python projects\venv\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Badboy\PycharmProjects\my python projects\venv\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Badboy\PycharmProjects\my python projects\venv\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Badboy\PycharmProjects\my python projects\venv\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\Badboy\\PycharmProjects\\my python projects\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\Badboy\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\Badboy\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\Badboy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running dist_info
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win32-3.8
    creating build\src.win32-3.8\numpy
    creating build\src.win32-3.8\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    ============================================================================
    error: Could not initialize compiler instance: do you have Visual Studio
    installed?  If you are trying to build with MinGW, please use "python setup.py
    build -c mingw32" instead.  If you have Visual Studio installed, check it is
    correctly installed, and the right version (VS 2008 for python 2.6, 2.7 and 3.2,
    VS 2010 for >= 3.3).

    Original exception was: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1\\lib', and the Compiler class was MSVCCompiler
    ============================================================================

    ----------------------------------------

Command ""C:\Users\Badboy\PycharmProjects\my python projects\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\Badboy\PycharmProjects\my python projects\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py" prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel C:\Users\Badboy\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpi7a2_egc" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Badboy\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy
```

Comment: It seems to be a problem with installing `numpy` on Python 3.8 https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13573 Try switching to the latest 3.8.1 to start with.

Comment: Random question here: why on Earth is python trying to know if the user has Visual Studio installed when trying to install NumPy in PyCharm???

Comment: @Shinratensei beause you need a compiler to compile the sources for that package if you do not use the binary packages.

Comment: And the only way to compile those in windows is through Visual Studio? Sorry I'm too used to using Linux for this stuff

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about installation by PyCharm. Try to install package by `pip install numpy` from cmd.

Comment: already installed numpy by cmd and it was successful. but couldnot install numpy package in pycharm.shows above error

Comment: PyCharm is also using pip, just the version set in the path or the venv. Just activate the venv you are using, then you can install it with binaries with pip.

Comment: @Frieder how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm tries to install the numpy sources and compile them (although I don't know why) you need a working compiler for this.
You could try to install the numpy (binary) packages with a default pip into your venv.

1. Open "cmd"
2. Go to correct dir: `cd "C:\Users\Badboy\PycharmProjects\my python projects"`
3. Activate the venv with the command: `venv\Scripts\activate.bat`
4. A new prefix (venv) should appear in your cmd
5. Install NumPy: `pip install numpy`